# centos delete files in n days ago

Tags: file, centos

My server is Centos 7.

My files structure is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   13968 مه    31 15:53 Data---2015-05-31---13:23:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   16037 مه    31 16:30 Data---2015-05-31---14:00:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   20379 مه    31 18:30 Data---2015-05-31---16:00:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   20379 مه    31 22:30 Data---2015-05-31---20:00:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   21892 ژوئن   1 10:30 Data---2015-06-01---08:00:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   25734 ژوئن   1 12:30 Data---2015-06-01---10:00:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   27880 ژوئن   1 14:30 Data---2015-06-01---14:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   33161 ژوئن   1 16:30 Data---2015-06-01---16:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   33179 ژوئن   1 18:30 Data---2015-06-01---18:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   35082 ژوئن   1 22:30 Data---2015-06-01---22:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   54499 ژوئن   2 10:30 Data---2015-06-02---10:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   57289 ژوئن   2 12:30 Data---2015-06-02---12:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   61077 ژوئن   2 14:30 Data---2015-06-02---14:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63617 ژوئن   2 16:30 Data---2015-06-02---16:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63619 ژوئن   2 18:30 Data---2015-06-02---18:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63722 ژوئن   2 22:30 Data---2015-06-02---22:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63722 ژوئن   3 10:30 Data---2015-06-03---10:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63722 ژوئن   3 12:30 Data---2015-06-03---12:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63723 ژوئن   3 14:30 Data---2015-06-03---14:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63723 ژوئن   3 16:30 Data---2015-06-03---16:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63722 ژوئن   3 18:30 Data---2015-06-03---18:30:01.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   63723 ژوئن   3 22:30 Data---2015-06-03---22:30:01.tar.gz
```

How can I delete files n days ago?

I use this commands and am not getting the correct result:

```
find CodeBackup/* -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm '{}' '+';
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete files greater 1 day old:

```
find CodeBackup -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```